# VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA in Visual Studio 2019/SSIS reading Timestamp-Column from PSDQL/ODBC

Tags: postgresql, ssis, timestamp, odbc, visual-studio-2019

I'm an Business Intelligence Developer. I'm developing for/maintaining a Microsoft BI Solution at our Company (SSIS,SSAS etc.). Recently I updated my Visual Studio to 2019 Enterprise (before that I was on 2015 Enterprise). Integration Services Extension Version 3.4. (also tested 3.2). With VS2015 everything was fine..

Part of our Data Warehouse is data coming from an PostgreSQL DB. I'm connecting to this using the official Postgres ODBC-Driver (32Bit, Unicode). I tried version 10.01 (old one, worked with VS15 without issues) and 12.01 (current one).

The Issue is the following: I opened the package I have the issues with. It warns me that the PSQL-ODBC-Datasource needs new metadata (nothing changed there nonetheless..). I can run the (unchanged) Package without any issues! Then I double-click the Source. A dialog pops up if I want to correct the Metadata of the Source according to the db it points to. Then the warning disappears. But If I run the package now it fails instantly telling me that the Source I just updated needs new Metadata.

I tracked the issue down to a minimal example. If I get data from a timestamp-column on the PSQL-ODBC-Datasource I allways get, immediately after execution of the package, an VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA-Error in Visual Studio (SSIS) and the package won't run. There is no yellow Exclamation-Mark on the Source like it is usual. Everything seems fine on design time. I can even preview the output of the source in it's properties. If I select another column instead of the timestamp-column there is no issue. If I select the timestamp-column again it again gives the error on runtime. I also tried different Postgres servers with different versions as Source and different ODBC-Drivers.

If I set ValidateExternalMetadat to False on the source everything is running fine, but this can't be the solution as it worked flawlessly previous.

It seems like SSIS-Packages created with Visual Studio 2019 can't retrieve timestamp-columns from PSQL-ODBC-Sources if ValidateExternalMetadata is enabled.. This is driving me nuts!

Did anyone have this issue and find a solution?

Greetings

*Edit*: Further Investigation: It seems like VS2019 translates a PostgreSQL Timestamp now to dbTimeStamp2 instead of dbTimeStamp (like 2015 did) on the Output-Columns. But the Metadata also stored in the Package-Xml seems like it's telling that the columns are dbTimeStamp. This mismatch seems to be the Core-Issue why the Package is telling the the Metadata needs to be updated!?

Answer (score 0):

OK I ran into the same problem here and it drove me crazy. I have the same setup and I got the exact same error messages.

Unfortunately I have no solution for this problem but at least I can tell you that it doesn't seem to be a isolated issue as I'm affected as well.

I overcame the problem for the time being by disabeling ValidateExternalMetadata but thats not a setup for production environments.

Thanks for this post though. I helped me not to feel like an idiot again. :D

Cheers
Daniel

Comment: Hey there, you're welcome ;) I reported the issue at the Q&A of the SSIS Extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects&ssr=false#qna) on 26.02.2020. They told me they will look into it and report back to me. So hopefully they fix it in the next version. I'm also kind of happy you are having the same issue. So there is a big chance that Microsoft can also reproduce it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the casing. I had a view (as data source) in development, with two columns in uppercase.

Before creating the view in production, I decided to change to lowercase both columns, just because all was in lowercase and that two columns were the only things in uppercase. Then I created the view.

My ETL ran fine in DEV, but it didn't in PROD. Finally, I realized that the difference in casing was the problem.

When I changed the view in PROD, so that it was the same as in DEV, it worked smoothly.